# Can't access to IIS using HTTP, only HTTPS

Tags: http, iis

In my IIS server, I can't access from HTTP, I can access only using HTTPS.

[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pii0X.png)

Only can access from the server (localhost).

I tried disabling the firewall, creating a new site using port 8080, but nothing works.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Thank you.

Comment: There might be no problem, but just some missing site binding, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Port binding is correct, the diagnosis was OK
https://imgur.com/a/q8gX73x
But it is inaccessible from any port, just for HTTP

Comment: The site binding `(*:8080:*)` looks good. But your browser error page shows a request to a domain, so have you checked DNS setting? Did you try that `http://158.xxxxx.xxx.xx` URL instead of the domain name?

Comment: What error code did the browser report? I suggest you use FRT to view IIS error log: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis